# sleeping while @PostConstruct does not trigger ContextClosedEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

From a Spring `@Component`, `@PostConstruct`, if the main thread goes to sleep for, say 30 seconds.

In between , a SIGTERM is triggered by running `kill <pid>`

But in this case neither `@PreDestroy`, nor `EventListener` on `ContextClosedEvent` gets triggered.

Which core Spring event can we listen to log for example when a bean is sleeping from `PostConstruct` and a SIGTERM is sent to spring boot app ?

Comment: I think the question you should be asking is "why is the main thread sleeping when it should be setting up the environment".

Comment: @Kayaman, so `Thread.currentThread().getName()` prints `main` from the `@Component` bean `@PostConstruct`. I think you are stating as `main` is sleeping, spring can't handle SIGTERM events meanwhile ?

Comment: No, I'm stating that you're asking the wrong question. If you're still running `@PostConstruct` code, then the environment isn't set up yet. Killing it at that point won't guarantee a graceful exit.

Comment: Said another way, since Spring is still in the process of initializing itself, it probably hasn't even gotten to the step of the initialization process where if registers the shutdown hook, so it is never even notified about the SIGTERM. --- More important though, is the simple *wrongness* of having a `@PostConstruct` method that sleeps. Why would it do that?

Comment: @Andreas, yeah sleep added just to simulate for example, in `@PostConstruct`, say bean is registering to multiple topics etc which is taking some time. In between some pending messages have started coming to first topic registered and being processed and then a SIGTERM by some orchestration system comes to java process. Now just was curious if we can gracefully handle it while bean was still registering for ex other subscribers to topics in example above

Comment: @fortm I doubt there's any guarantee in Spring for it, so you shouldn't be trying to solve it on the Spring side. Maybe concentrate on the orchestration system instead, so it doesn't go around killing things randomly (if it's still setting up, why is it getting killed already?)

Comment: @Kayaman, so the `@PostConstruct` itself was taking time around 60 sec in one of beans to register topics and health check was not up as a result within grace period. This caused orchestration to send SIGTERM. But understood your points above .

Comment: @fortm so your problem is actually that you're performing too much work in `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per one of comments, problem is too much logic in `@PostConstruct`

> so your problem is actually that you're performing too much work in @PostConstruct
>
> Said another way, since Spring is still in the process of initializing itself, it probably hasn't even gotten to the step of the initialization process where if registers the shutdown hook, so it is never even notified about the SIGTERM